# On iPhone 6+ my text message shows my husbands name as sender, not mine

Tags: iphone

How do I have my name show as text message sender?
I have tried Settings, messages but have not found the place to change it.

Answer (score 2):

The recipient has an address book entry of your number and/or email address with your husband's name. The easiest way to fix this is to send them your address book card - share it from the contacts app.